# How to allow user to change his attributes?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to figure out how to allow users to change their profile. I have a `Users` extended  by `User Profile` (OneToOne).

I was thinking about changing registration view, prefill user's attributes and allow him to change them. But it is not probably the good way.

Could you give me a hint how to do that?

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1','password2', 'first_name', 'last_name')

    def clean(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')

        if password1 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")

        return self.cleaned_data

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('telephone','marital_status','how_do_you_know_about_us')
```

**MODELS.PY**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # ATRIBUTY KTORE BUDE MAT KAZDY
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=40,null=True)

    HOW_DO_YOU_KNOW_ABOUT_US_CHOICES = (
            ('coincidence',u'It was coincidence'),
            ('relative_or_friends','From my relatives or friends'),
            )
    how_do_you_know_about_us = models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=HOW_DO_YOU_KNOW_ABOUT_US_CHOICES, null=True)

    MARITAL_STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('single','Single'),
        ('married','Married'),
        ('separated','Separated'),
        ('divorced','Divorced'),
        ('widowed','Widowed'),
    )
    marital_status = models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=MARITAL_STATUS_CHOICES, null=True)

    # OD KIAL STE SA O NAS DOZVEDELI
    # A STAV

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.user.first_name,self.user.last_name)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.user.first_name,self.user.last_name)
```

**REGISTRATION VIEW:**

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST)
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():

            user = user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user_form.cleaned_data['password1'])
            user.save()

            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user

            profile.save()
            return register_success(request)

        else:
            print user_form.errors, profile_form.errors

    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        profile_form = UserProfileForm()

    return render(request, "auth/registration/register.html",
                  context={'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form})
```

EDIT:

This is the view I'm trying to create but it does not autofill form:

```
@login_required
def edit_profile(request):
    myUser = request.user
    user_form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=myUser)
    user_profile_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=myUser)

    context={'user_form': user_form,
             'user_profile_form':user_profile_form}
    return render(request, 'auth/profiles/my_profile.html', context=context)
```

Comment: I don't understand, what makes you think it's not a good way?

Comment: I don't know, I supposed that there is some built in module to do this. But it does not work. I've uploaded a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `edit_profile` view you added, you're passing your forms a POST request argument. You should only be passing this argument on a POST request. So update your forms to be the following if the request is a GET request:

views.py

```
user_form = UserForm(instance=myUser)
user_profile_form = UserProfileForm(instance=myUser)
```

forms.py

```
# Something like this will only save password if data is entered in one of the password fields
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(UserForm, self).clean()
    password1 = cleaned_data.get('password1', None)
    password2 = cleaned_data.get('password2', None)
    old_password = cleaned_data.get('old_password', None)
    if password1 or password2:
        if password1 != password2:
            self._errors['password1'] = 'New Password and Confirm New Password must match.'
            self._errors['password2'] = 'New Password and Confirm New Password must match.'
        if not self.user.check_password(old_password):
            self._errors['old_password'] = 'Your old password was entered incorrectly.'
    return cleaned_data

def save(self, request):
    user = self.user
    if self.cleaned_data.get('password1', None):
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data.get('password1'))
        update_session_auth_hash(request, user)
    user.save()
    return user
```

For your choices issue, you can specify choices as an argument when specifying widgets for the field.

Comment: Thanks curtis, this works, but partially. The choice forms are not filled. Do you know what is the problem? The active user has these forms filled already. And how to exclude password1 and password2?

Comment: And the telephone is not filled too. It's probably because I'm putting User as an attribute but in the second form, there should be UserProfile. But how can I get it using user instance?

Comment: I've updated my answer to address the choice form fields and the passwords. See if you can use that to as a start. For the user_profile_form, keep in mind you want a user's profile instance, not necessarily the instance of the user itself. Also note I've added an `old_password` field to the form (unbound field). I find it's good practice to confirm the password before allowing them to change it.

Comment: Hint... You need to follow the reverse relationship of the one to one relation